# Want to fetch options on change of inputValue in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-select

I have a react-select component, I want to add a functionality such that as soon as somebody types something in the react-select, There should be a api request that would fetch the items related to that keyword entered, How can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try looking into AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async'
Then create a function in your component to load the options from your API which should accept an input string and a callback and should make the API call based on the input string. Something like this

```
const loadOptions = (inputValue, callback) => {
    // api call here
    fetch('your-api-url?${inputValue}')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
         // do your work here
         const options = //transform data here
         callback(options)
      });
};
```

Then in your componen pass your loadOptions function into the loadOptions prop

```
const YourComponent = () => {
    return (
       <AsyncSelect
         cacheOptions
         defaultOptions
         loadOptions={loadOptions}
       />
    );
};
```

Comment: This works but i also want to add a 500ms wait in search, I dont want to search for every character change, how can i do that?

Comment: I tried using clearing and setting a timer using useState, and when the timer shoots 500ms then i search, but this didnt work because i think for every charcter change the AsyncSelect by default sends a request

Comment: Right to do this you'll want to implement a debounce. You can use the lodash library and then wrap the loadOptions function in the debounce method with the time you want to set the delay for. For example:
`const loadOptions = debounce((inputValue, callback) => { your code here}, 500); //500ms delay`
Of course you'll have to install the lodash libray

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything worked

Answer (score 0):

Well You can do this without any API call just use the filter method to filter your options

Comment: more a comment than an answer